# How to modify the XML Stream generated from an XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlwriter

I need to take the XML generated by a XmlWriter and modify it. Is it possible?

Being "writer" the XmlWriter, "writeStream" an IOStream and "value" a List of items, here is the code to write with XmlWriter:

```
writer.WriteRaw("<array>");                      
                    writer.WriteRaw("<curLength>" + ((IList)value).Count + "</curLength>");
                    writer.Close();

                    serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);


                    XmlWriter loopWriter;
                    foreach (object o in (IList)value)
                    {
                        loopWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writeStream, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });
                        serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());

                        serializer.Serialize(loopWriter, o);
                        loopWriter.Close();
                    }                        

                    writer = CreateXmlWriter(writeStream, content);
                    writer.WriteRaw("</array>");                        
                    writer.Close();
```

And after that i want to take the stream generated by the XmlWriter and modify it, doing something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(writeStream);

                    var elements = doc.GetElementsByTagName("struct");
                    int numberOfElements = elements.Count;
                    for(int i=1; i<=numberOfElements; i++)
                    {                            
                        XmlNode element = elements.Item(i);
                        XmlElement indexElement = doc.CreateElement("index");
                        indexElement.InnerText = i.ToString();
                        element.InsertAfter(indexElement,element);
                    }
```

But, if i execute the code, it throws a "NotSupportedException" at the line of "doc.Load(writeStream);"

Thank you!

Comment: Your stream probably do not offer Read operations or is in a state where it can't be read that's why it's returning NotSupported when XMLDocument tries to read it, check the exception message and you will find out the real problema.

Comment: Thanx, now i know that the "writeStream" is a HttpResponseStream. I think that it is not possible to read from that kind of stream, or is it? And that would be the reason why the Load method throws the exception, so any idea how to read from that stream?